# .Net remote debugging Win2003 website with VS 2012

Tags: .net, remote-debugging

I am trying to install the VS2012 remote debugger X86 version on a Windows 2003 in order to debug a web app from a computer that only has VS2012 installed. 
I am getting Newer Windows version required for this program message.
Does VS2012 remote debugger still supports Windows 2003?
Is there another way to debug the app using VS2012? I've tried to connect the VS2010 remote debugger with VS2012 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The VS2012 remote debugger doesn't support Windows 2003 http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility. And the VS2012 can't connect to a VS2010 debugger as you've already noticed. So I'm afraid it is impossible to debug remotely a Win2003 server with VS2012.