# Debugging VS2012 Service on Windows 2003

Tags: debugging, service, windows-services, remote-debugging

I'm trying to attach a debugger to a windows service running on a Windows 2003R2 box using VS2012. I've installed the VS2012 SP1 debugging tools and set to 'No Authentication', but I just get a 'Connection request was rejected by the remote debugger. Ensure that the remote debugger is running in "No Authentication" mode.

Is it possible to debug with this setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267423/net-remote-debugging-win2003-website-with-vs-2012