# How do I debug a running process?

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a process that I am running and it should have finished a long time ago. It's been running 13 hours, and I expected it to be done in just a few. It has run successfully before many times.

It's possible it is just processing a lot of data, so I don't want to just stop it in the middle in case it legitimately just needed that much time and it's almost done.

How can I attach to the process to see if it is just sitting there or if it is actually processing? Can I break in and see what line it is on, and get a count of how many records it's processed so far?

I have windbg installed but I'm not sure if that is the right tool. I have the source code for this application as well if I need that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Visual Studio.

Open up the solution for the project and from the Debug menu, select Attach to Process.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install visual studio on the server it's running on.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde you could install the remote debugger.

Comment: once it attaches to process, then what? do I just set a breakpoint where I think it is processing?

Comment: The application is running on a Windows Server 2003 server and the process i .net 4.0...I tried installing visual studio 2012 and it fails every time.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde attach it on your machine. just hit the pause button.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use visual studio you can use remote debugging. You still need to install [the remote debugger client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx), but it is a small installation and won't require a restart (afair)

Comment: Once I install remote debugging, then I can attach to the process from within the project that created the application and set a break point?

Comment: The application is running on a Windows Server 2003 server and the process i .net 4.0...I tried installing the debugger and it says it needs a newer version of windows.

Comment: Weird, I did not think the remote debugger supported only specific windows versions. Are you sure you tried to install the correct version (x86 for 32 bit or x64 for 64 bit)?

Comment: Yes, it's an x64 version of Win2k3 and I tried installing the x64 version.

Comment: Hmm seems it is not supported (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267423/net-remote-debugging-win2003-website-with-vs-2012) I guess your options are to install vs2010 and use the remote debugger of that version or use windbg (which has a pretty steep learning curve). Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You say you have windbg installed but I'm not sure if by that you mean on your dev machine or on the machine on which the long running process is running. If it's the latter, and since this is a .NET process, the bitness of windbg and the process must match (eg. 32 bit windbg to debug 32 bit .NET process OR 64 bit windbg to debug 64 bit process). Once you determine the bitness of the process, then attach the bitness matching windbg to the process (File | Attach to a Process...)

Then fix your symbols path with `.symfix;.reload`

Next load the managed debugging extension with `.loadby sos.dll clr`

(Note: The above works for .NET v4 and above. Prior versions of .NET need `.loadby sos.dll mscorwks`)

Now you can dump all your managed thread stacks with `~*e !clrstack` and inspect each managed stack to see what each thread is up to.

Another thing to try is to see the last managed exception for each managed thread with `!threads`. This will list each managed thread and indicate the last managed exception for that thread, if one exists. You can then inspect the managed exception with `!pe <ex-addr>`