# Attach debugger to remote DLL PDB called from Vendor Application

Tags: c#, remote-debugging, vendor

I have a Vendor Application that calls my Class Library (a DLL). The Vendor instantiates my class using their EXE with the following VB code:

```
Dim objCustom As Object = System.Activator.CreateInstance("stuffGuiCustom", "stuff.stuffGuiCustom.clsCustomSandbox").Unwrap
```

After that, they set two properties:

```
objCustom.propform = mfrm
objCustom.propParent = objSandbox
```

After that, they call a function within my code called `main`:

```
Call objCustom.main(objCustom, objGlobals, , clsSandbox)
```

Of course, I don't have any Type or Interface definitions for objSandbox, which the vendor has identified as the key object which contains everything I need.

My DLL has been written on my development machine, however, the application that calls my Assembly is on a remote machine (I have Network Admin and Local Admin rights to the machine).

**Here's my question:**
How do I attach my Visual Studio Debugger to the DLL so when the remote application instantiates it, I can debug?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If your development machine and the applicationn that calls your dll are on the same network 
you can use Visual Studio Remote Debugging.

1. First you have to copy your PDB files into the remote machine, next to the dll.
2. Install VS Remote Debugger on the remote machine and open it.
3. Start the app on the remote machine
4. Attach to it from your local VS.

In the "Attach to process" dialog from VS you must pass the identifier that VS Remote Debugger gives you into the "Qualifier" edit. Afterwards, you will see all the processes from that machine in your VS dialog and select the application that loads your assembly.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx) you can find more information about how to set up VS Remote Debugger

Comment: I've been researching this, and I appreciate the feedback. Another friend of mine suggested the same thing. The remote machine is Windows 2003, I am using VS 2012...and I tried to install the Remote Debugging Tools but was informed by the installer that they didn't support that version of Windows (see this StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267423/net-remote-debugging-win2003-website-with-vs-2012). Either way, an upvote for a technically correct answer (even if I can't utilize it). I'll just have to install the Vendor Application on my Dev machine (sigh).

Comment: You can try using WinDbg in the remote machine, but you will not be able to debug it on your local machine, you can just debug it there. I'm not really familiar with this method, but you can find more info here: [WinDbg for .NET developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/11/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers.aspx)